# In Advaita Vedanta, after realizing one's true nature, does one develop dissociated identity/apathy to their body?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, brahman

When one realizes the Brahman, the role of the body as just a physical vessel to travel through the transactional reality becomes apparent. So in that case, does one start to havea dissociated identity to their body?

Like just stop caring about what my body feels or experiences. I just take everything as it comes, since karma only sticks to this body and not my true self. One does good just for the sake of doing something. There is nothing to gain or lose.

For example, I might get sick, I do the minimum to get myself checked as am apathetic towards my body. Or, I burn my hands, I feel the pain but the scar or the blister doesn't really bother me as it is just a transactional reality. Or do some charity work, get duped by organizers for a million dollars and lose every bit of possessions. I don't feel any concern about my next meal or my place to sleep, for it's just a maya. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes and No. The main difference between realized and unrealized is like between a programmer and gamer. A gamer focus is to only enjoy a mobile or computer game without concerning  how the game was designed, but a programmer knows the inner coding of game. Similarly, common people want to go with social rules, customs, worship Gods, have family, earn wealth without knowing how and why this matrix Maya was set up in the first place but ending in death. Read Gita for understanding Atman, even Krishna had atman gyan, but he was a just king.Dharma, Artha, Kama, Moksha is the order to be followed.

Answer (score 2):

Srimad Bhagavatam 11.13.36

> dehaṁ ca naśvaram avasthitam utthitaṁ vā
> siddho na paśyati yato 'dhyagamat svarūpam
> daivād apetam atha daiva-vaśād upetaṁ
> vāso yathā parikṛtaṁ madirā-madāndhaḥ

"               , ,      -                   . ,   ’         ’      ,  -    ,              ."

Commentary by Sri Vishvanath Chakravarti

> Two verses describe the state of the person who has perfected , jñāna who is jévanmukta.  He does not pay attention when he has risen from a seat or sits down again because he has attained realization of Brahman (svarüpam).  An example is given.  A drunken person is not aware if he is wearing or not wearing clothing.

Srimad Bhagavatam 11.13.37

> deho 'pi daiva-vaśa-gaḥ khalu karma yāvat
> svārambhakaṁ pratisamīkṣata eva sāsuḥ
> taṁ sa-prapañcam adhirūḍha-samādhi-yogaḥ
> svāpnaṁ punar na bhajate pratibuddha-vastuḥ

"            ,         ,               ,                 ."

Commentary by Sri Vishvanath Chakravarti

> As long has one has karmas to be experienced even the liberated person will continue living while observing his experience of karma.
> Will he sometimes become attached again?
> No.
> He does not enjoy the body with senses, senses objects and material enjoyment.  He is like a person who has woken up and does not experience the dream body again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering it from the perspective of my guru.
Actually if you've realized the Brahman nature of yourself, you don't have to give up everything and give away all your wealth to charity. You just realize that this whole world is a playground, you just play your part. You'll be unaffected by the ups and downs of the life and you just see the life as it is. This play should go on as it is and you just see yourself as a player who's playing knowing the player nature.
The whole realization is to free you from the suffering of human nature. The illustrations you gave are not of a realised one but a person who is Tamasic, lazy and lethargic.
As said in the Bhagavad Gita 2.55, when one discards all selfish desires and cravings of the senses that torment the mind, and becomes satisfied in the realization of the self, such a person is said to be transcendentally situated. So you'll transcend the desires and fear. Greatest of the sorrows cannot shatter you.